# Google Spreadsheet Form Responses in to an already made sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-forms

I have a template form and matching spreadsheet that need to be copied multiple times.  When I make copies of the two, the copies are not linked for the form responses to go to the newly copied spreadsheet.  The template spreadsheet is heavily formatted, so I don't want to create a new form response sheet in that existing spreadsheet (I know it gives you that option.).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to create a new "form responses", make a copy of the forms (Not the response sheet). In the copied form, Change the response sheet to the one with all the formatting by going to:Menu>Responses> Change responses destination